# Sub Queries with Multiple WHERE statement...

Tags: sql

I am New to SQL... Please dont mind if I ask for silly question..
Here is my first Query which should execute data based on code **WHERE hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL**

I have multiple SELECT, FROM and WHERE statement. How do I correct this.

```
SELECT

date,fullvisitorid AS Users,
hits.product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name,
(hits.product.productPrice/1000000) AS Product_Price,
(hits.product.productQuantity) AS Product_Quantity,
(hits.product.productrevenue/1000000) AS Product_Revenue

FROM ([DATASET])

WHERE hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL

-------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Product_Viewed

FROM ([DATASET])

WHERE hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'
```

Comment: What is it you would exactly like to achieve? Can you provide an example with table data and expected output?

Comment: The first SELECT returns 5 columns, the SECOND just one. How do you want to "combine" those result sets?

Comment: date, Users, Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Quantity, Product_Revenue - All these columns are available in one table and I am pulling these all together to one visual where I can show total product viewed Vs Total Product Revenue Vs Total Product Quantity however the only column Product_Viewed can be pulled with condition as '2' and rest all should be pulled If hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL.... OR else all these columns will pull data with NULL value

Comment: I still don't get it. Edit the question and add some sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine this like

```
SELECT
date,fullvisitorid AS Users,
hits.product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name,
(hits.product.productPrice/1000000) AS Product_Price,
(hits.product.productQuantity) AS Product_Quantity,
(hits.product.productrevenue/1000000) AS Product_Revenue,
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Product_Viewed
from ([DATASET])
WHERE hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL 
AND
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'
```

Comment: Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Quantity and Product_Revenue column should reflect basis on condition hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL and Product_Viewed should reflect basis on hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'.... Yes there are two condition for different column

Answer (score 0):

When you want to combine multiple conditions in the `WHERE` clause, use [AND/OR](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) keywords.

```
SELECT

date,fullvisitorid AS Users,
hits.product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name,
(hits.product.productPrice/1000000) AS Product_Price,
(hits.product.productQuantity) AS Product_Quantity,
(hits.product.productrevenue/1000000) AS Product_Revenue,
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Product_Viewed

FROM ([DATASET])

WHERE hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
AND
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'
```

Comment: Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Quantity and Product_Revenue column should reflect basis on condition hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL and Product_Viewed should reflect basis on hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'

Comment: You mean `hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL` should be applicable only for the columns you have mentioned?

Comment: Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Quantity and Product_Revenue column should reflect basis on condition hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL and Product_Viewed should reflect basis on hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'.... Yes there are two condition for different column